# How do I capture hs_err_pid.log in container environments

Tags: docker, segmentation-fault, jvm, kubernetes-pod

When i run my jar application, the jvm is getting crash with the error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003fd6, pid=7, tid=0x00007ff273404b38
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.60.0.22-SA-linux-musl-x64) (8.0_322-b06) (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.322-b06 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000003fd6
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /usr/app/core or core.7
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/app/hs_err_pid7.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://www.azul.com/support/
#
```

The error says that a report file is saved `hs_err_pid7.log`, but i'm not able to view it because as soon as the jvm crashes, the container stops running, Is there a way to save this file outside the container?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get the contents of the hs_err_pidx.log into the logs of your container.
I.e. setting `ErrorFile` property to `/proc/1/fd/1`.

You can set it directly via command parameter: `-XX:ErrorFile=/proc/1/fd/1'`

... or via an environment variable. E.g.: `_JAVA_OPTIONS='-XX:ErrorFile=/proc/1/fd/1'`

For me this worked in a container running on Kubernetes with an Alpine-based image and a RedHat OpenJDK 17.

Answer (score -1):

Try to mount persistent volume rather than the bind volume !

Comment: Hi @Bathini Ravi, thanks for the help, Can you share any reference guide, which can help

Comment: If this is a standalone Dockerfile you can try this  ! type of the mount as "volume".  https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).